# Excel Add-in not show up in 64 bit Excel (Add-In Express)

Tags: excel, add-in, rtd

I have an Excel add-in (COM AddIn, XLL, RTD) , created with C#, VS2010, Add-In Express 2010,  I  install it on a PC with win  64 bit + Excel 2010 64 bit without error, but it does not show up at all. (no toolbar, no ribbon, not in inactive addin list, not in disabled addin list)
I searched there is even no adxloader.log or adxregistrator.log 
It works fine on VMs (with win 7 64 bit + Excel 64 bit).

When I include the addin as component in the other addin (ExcelDNA), and install it, now the install failed with error as the following

```
[EXCEPTION_UNHANDLED] (0xc0000005) at address [0x988a840f]

                *** Stack Trace (x86) ***

[0x988a840f]  -----
[0x725de54b]  MsiLoadStringW()
[0x725de4e7]  MsiLoadStringW()
[0x7263a466]  MsiInvalidateFeatureCache()
[0x72695b92]  MsiGetPropertyW()
[0x0009b2ab]  -----
[0x000b0b76]  -----
[0x000aa444]  -----
[0x000a8177]  -----
[0x000a70f6]  -----
[0x000ada7c]  -----
[0x000b266e]  -----
[0x000b263b]  -----
[0x000b2442]  -----
[0x0005d5a7]  -----
[0x0005d7bc]  -----
[0x0005d72c]  -----
[0x0005de95]  -----
[0x770b9ef2]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
[0x770b9ec5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain()
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of only one reason for an XLL add-in not working in Excel 2010 x64 - a bug in .NET Framework 2.0 (the Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate method). But this is obviously not your case, we see that installation completes successfully but the add-in does not get registered and no logs are created. It looks like custom actions of your setup project do not work for some reason.

Anyway, it is difficult to say anything with 100% certainty without seeing your project. Please contact our support team with more details, we will try to find the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to rebuild class interface

Check these:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/0b296092-3eae-457b-8628-a6b67d679d0e

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx

http://www.ironshay.com/post/Developing-Excel-Functions-in-C-for-Excel-2010-64-Bit.aspx